How would pregnancy of a half human/Fae work for both human and fae?
I’m in the middle of world building for a fantasy novel, and I’m trying to figure out how the mixing of winged/unwinged fae and humans would work? I’m pulling inspiration from Sarah J Maas, I love the idea of having pregnancy for the fae being rare and being more difficult/ deadly for different races to give birth to mixed babies but I don’t want to steal her entire thing. I’m starting of with a long peace period that has allowed the fae and humans to intermingle which would lead to mixed children. Is there any fae mythology that can give me a more in depth idea at how long and how difficult fae conception/ gestation is? And how would a half fae baby affect a human mothers survival rate?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I guess I just need to know, how does inter species pregnancy work? Without stealing from another author

"how does inter species pregnancy work" well...it doesn't. Literally the definition of "species" is that members of it can produce offspring. Therefore, by definition, members of different species cannot. Not normally: only in fantasy and IRL via artificial means.

@VLAZ: Bzzzzzt! Wrong. That's not even a definition of species, let alone the definition of species. You may be thinking of Ernst Mayr's definition of a biological species, which requires reproductive isolation. But first, it is only one of many definitions, because biology is messy and boundaries between species are fuzzy; and second, it requires reproductive isolation, not perfect reproductive isolation, and it does not require any special form of reproductive isolation. For example, two species can be reproductively isolated because they live far away from one another.

You need to make up your own mind on this. You have a wide range of options, but there is no objectively "correct" answer that we can supply, because fae are fictional creatures. Also, we don't know what you think they are like, but that's a secondary problem. Wikipedia's page on Ligers may stimulate thoughts.

@VLAZ: For a trivial example, horses and donkeys routinely mate and produce offspring, called mules. For another trivial example, wolves, dogs, coyotes and jackals are completely interfertile to the point where it is sometimes difficult to assign a specific individual to one or another species.

If you want an answer from this stack you should provide us with a detailed description of faes in your world. Otherwise you ask us to build your world for you, which is prohibited. For example if your faes are really tiny like tinkerbell from peter pan -> no way a fea could survive even the early stages of being pregnant with a half-human. However if your faes are basically "humans with wings" the anwser is obviously "no problem at all".

To the same end as datacube's questions, I'd question the fundamental mythos of the fae.  In many mythos, the fae are fickle.  In those mythos, how the pregnancy goes would be less tied to any physics or general rule and more tied to what idle promises were made during the act of conception.

It's been quite awhile since I binged on Irish folklore, but I think the jury was out on whether there were no issues with interbreeding, or whether the children of such unions were disfigured and discarded (mixing in with changeling stories).  Definitely, the common Selkie-type stories quite often involved having children with the captive Selkie before she found her hidden pelt.  There wasn't a lot of thought about species as we currently think about it.

Though in line with the idea of changelings (disfigured fairy children and /or the discarded elderly disguised as children to substitute for stolen human babies)...  Humans were enough like the fairies that human children COULD be stolen and raised as fairies.  Or attractive women (or men) could be stolen as spouses.

When you say "mythology," were you looking for folklore from our world or tropes used in modern fiction? I mainly ask because there are also stacks for Mythology & Folklore and for Science Fiction & Fantasy in case you still want more information.


Is there any fae mythology that can give me a more in depth idea at how long and how difficult fae conception/ gestation is?

None whatsoever — and thank goodness
I'd like to invite you to think a bit about what you're asking. You're starting with something fictional, you want to develop something that's also fictional, but you're asking about an aspect of both fictional issues as if it's factual. When looked at in this light, I hope you will agree with me that the question doesn't make sense.
Despite being a sincere believer in God, I recognize that it was and is the habit of humanity to invent fiction to rationalize the world around them. We're still doing it. It doesn't matter which side of the political fence an American citizen was on in 2020, but sometime late that year someone invented a fiction to rationalize either the presidential win on one side or the loss on the other. (We're still arguing about it!) Humans are, in fact, really good at rationalizing our world via fiction.
What we're really bad at is creating all the pseudo-scientific details (c.f. the previous example...). Consequently, it shouldn't surprise you at all that no mythology has dealt in any specific way with conception, gestation, and delivery of cross-breed events unless one or the other of those issues had a moral or parabolic (the version of that word that applies to parables, not parabolas...) purpose.
And many worldbuilders seem to forget that the purpose of building a world (OK, other than for the pure joy of it) is to tell a story. And the purpose of telling a story (a good one that will be remembered by more than a couple of friends) is to send a message. Thus, if a mythical cross-breed pregnancy (we can find a few in Greek and Roman mythology) didn't serve a message pertaining to such details, no such details were included.
And they weren't. At least not the details you're talking about. In mythology and fiction, women died in childbirth to serve the story, not because it was a fact of the development of a plausibly scientifically rationalized world. (I put a few words in your mouth, forgive me, I'm stressing a point.)
This is actually good news for you!
What this means is this: if it actually makes sense for the purposes of your storybuilding, you have the privilege of defining what pregnancy means in your world. And we're more than happy to help you work out those details! But there are times when the only permissible answer is, "roll 4D4 (four 4-sided dice) for the number of months of gestation" because the detail doesn't matter scientifically or historically. It only matters in the context of your story.
To that end it's worth mentioning narrative necessity. Narrative necessity is that aspect of worldbuilding where the rule of the world (e.g., the gestational period of a fae-human pregnancy) depends on the needs of the story and not on any scientific, historical, or even logical fact. For example, I can easily imagine that giving birth to a creature with wings would be painful and dangerous to a human. But I can also imagine that the undeveloped wings have no less flexibility than any baby's arms and legs. Indeed, I can trivially imagine a world where the undeveloped wings are quite short and soft, meaning they have no negative impact whatsoever on the mother (or, at least, no more than any human-human conception would have).1 There is no right answer! There is only the answer that serves the needs of your story and helps build a consistent and usable world.
That's the nature of the universe you're currently bathed in — the universe of worldbuilding where you get to decide how your world will operate. You decide what a fae is. You decide what happens when fae and humans mate. It's a great place to be! And more often than you might believe, there isn't Real World data to depend on during your acts of creation.
So... you tell us... how long is the gestational period and how dangerous is it?
An important note about the usefulness of this service
You're a first-time user and THANK YOU for joining us! Please be aware that it's common for people to approach us with questions like those you've asked. These are questions of the general form, "I have X and Y, what's the consequence?" That's actually a really hard question to answer because, as I mentioned, there's less specific, objective, and definitive information out there than you might think.
Our sweet spot is "I have X and Y and I want Z to be the consequence. How can I rationalize that?" In other words, you've already made the fundamental worldbuilding choice and now you want help working out the details. We're whomping good with that! We can, for example, bring up details of cross-breeding animals, even plants, as examples of what you can use to fill in the details in your world.
We look forward to helping you build your world!

1 If you really want to have fun with this, most winged critters on Earth are born via an external egg. So let's define your fae such that they give birth by laying eggs. A successful male-fae/female-human conception would result in the human egg developing into a fae-style egg in utero that must be either (a) passed by the human female without cracking the eggshell or (b) must lead to the egg cracking in utero to deliver the baby and the egg remains in a similar but much more dangerous way a placenta is passed in Real Life. There's a lot of opportunity in this if you want to grab hold of it.
